# <p:growl> and <p:messages> in a same page

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want use `<p:messages>` to display error message, use `<p:growl>` to display success messages.
In the backing bean:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(title, msg));
```

But I found whatever I add message in the backing bean, `<p:messages>` and `<p:growl>` both display it.

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the [growl's demo page of PrimeFaces](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/growl.xhtml), they mentioned that: "*Growl simply replaces h:messages component.*". I'm afraid that you may not be able to achieve your goal because growl will also display all FacesMessage in the View.

However, if you reverse your requirement - display errors using `<p:growl>` & display successful messages using `<p:message>`, you can actually achieve that as following:

```
<p:message id="successMsg" for="successMsg" />

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MrBean {

   public void doSomething() {
      FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 

      if (failed) {
         context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Failed", "Sry boss! I have failed.")); 

      } else {
         context.addMessage("successMsg", new FacesMessage("Successful", "Hey boss! I did it!"));

      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean addMessage could special the id of `<p:messages>`, but doesn't works for `<p:growl>` ?

Comment: Be careful! I am using `<p:message>`, not `<p:messages>`

Answer (score 11):

JSF:

```
<p:messages for="somekey" />
<p:growl for="anotherkey" />
```

Bean:

```
context.addMessage("somekey", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Sample info message", "PrimeFaces Rocks"));
context.addMessage("somekey", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Sample info message", "Always bet on Prime"));a
context.addMessage("anotherkey", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Sample info message", "PrimeFaces is developed by Chuck Norris"));
```

This just worked fine with me!

Answer (score 10):

It looks like as of PrimeFaces 3.3 you can do what you wanted to do:

http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1894

You can now do:

```
<p:messages severity="error" />
<p:growl severity="info, warn" />
```

with

```
context.addMessage("somekey", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Error Title", "Error Message"));
context.addMessage("somekey", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Success Title", "Success Message"));
```

Answer (score 2):

This maybe an old question, but maybe this is relevant still:

I had this same situation come up, I worked it out using the `for` statement in each tag

```
<p:growl id="someid" for="growl" />
<p:messages id="messageid" for="messages" />
```

and the backing bean:

```
context.addMessage("growl", new FacesMessage("Successful", "to growl"));
context.addMessage("messages", new FacesMessage("Successful", "to messages"));
```

just as a side note, if you add `autoupdate="true"` then the messages will get reset for both growl and messages (if you add messages to growl, messages will get cleared)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a p:growl that doesn't render when there are only validation errors.

```
<p:growl 
    id="growl" 
    sticky="true" 
    showDetail="true" 
    rendered="#{not facesContext.validationFailed}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a separate messages panel for growl and messages and update this panel when i submit the form as following:

```html
 <p:panel id="messages">
    <p:messages for="errorMsg" showDetail="true" />
    <p:growl for="infoMsg" showDetail="true" />
    <p:growl globalOnly="true" />
 </p:panel>

<p:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" update="messages" actionListener="#{yourManagedBean.submit}" />
```

In ManagedBean

```
     // display submit info - showDetail="true" in infoMsg will show details message
     FacesMessage infoMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Submit Info", "Your details info message." );
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("infoMsg", infoMsg);

     // display error message - e is instance of Exception
     FacesMessage errMsg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error Occured", e.getMessage());
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("errorMsg", errMsg);


     // display some generic message (with no details in growl)
     FacesMessage genericMsg = new FacesMessage("Generic Message");
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, genericMsg);
```

I have tested this using Primefaces 5.0.

Enjoy!